# Why does it say (in python) "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'yes' referenced before assignment" when I already defined the variable?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
from random import randint

ant1 = 1
ant2 = 2
ant3 = 3
ant4 = 4
cntNum = 0
no = 0
yes = 0

def antMove(antNum):
    randomNum = randint(0,3)
    if randomNum == antNum:
        yes += 1
    else:
        print("No")   

while cntNum < 20:
    antMove(ant1)
    antMove(ant2)
    antMove(ant3)
    antMove(ant4)
    cntNum = cntNum + 1

if cntNum == 20:
    print(yes)
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: sry, my bad: line 12 and 17

Comment: full error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/2020_dimitri_kachler/Desktop/Ant.py", line 17, in <module>
    antMove(ant1)
  File "/Users/2020_dimitri_kachler/Desktop/Ant.py", line 12, in antMove
    yes += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'yes' referenced before assignment
>>>

Answer (score 3):

The important part of the message is bold: Unbound**Local**Error: **local variable** 'yes' referenced before assignment.

In the following line, you are trying to update the value of the `yes` variable which does not exist in the **local** scope of the function:

```
yes += 1
```

I assume you wanted to update the **global** `yes` variable. In this case you have to declare the `yes`variable as global in your function:

```
def antMove(antNum):
    global yes
```

But it is admitted that it is a bad pratice and you should find a nicer way to achieve what your want.

Answer (score 2):

You got a scope issue here. Inside your script, `yes` apperas 2 times. 1 time as a global variable and 1 time as a — not existent - local one. Beside of the fact, that this is dangerous, you can solve your issue with something like

```
def antMove(antNum):
    global yes
    randomNum = randint(0,3)
    if randomNum == antNum:
        yes += 1
    else:
        print("No")
```

Do you see the `global yes` statement? This allows you to write the global variable `yes`inside context of the method.

In most cases I have seen this, global is a sign for either people coming from C or bad coding. If you reuse your little script it will be fun to debug a wrong increasing of `yes`.